# webpart control in master page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, web-parts

I have a webpart in a control that I am using on a webpage. The webpage uses a master page and there is a content holder in the MP that can hold controls for alignment/design issues. Everything works well with this but the webpart control. When i put the webpart in the container i lose the ability to move the webparts around but as soon as i move it out of the container it works fine.

default.aspx

```
/// <summary>
        /// Set the selected item equal to the current display mode.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyWebPartManager wpm = (MyWebPartManager)WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);


            Control control = (Control)Master.FindControl("divReturnBack");
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Visible = true;
                control.Controls.Add(DisplayModeMenul1);
            }
        }
```

displaymode.ascx

```
MyWebPartManager webPartManager;

        public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.InitComplete += new EventHandler(InitComplete);
        }
        public void InitComplete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            webPartManager = (MyWebPartManager)WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);
            String browseModeName = WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode.Name;

            foreach (WebPartDisplayMode mode in
              webPartManager.SupportedDisplayModes)
            {
                String modeName = mode.Name;
                if (mode.IsEnabled(webPartManager))
                {
                    ListItem listItem = new ListItem(modeName, modeName);
                    ddlDisplayMode.Items.Add(listItem);
                }
            }
        }

        public void ddlDisplayMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String selectedMode = ddlDisplayMode.SelectedValue;

            WebPartDisplayMode mode = webPartManager.SupportedDisplayModes[selectedMode];
            if (mode != null)
            {
                webPartManager.DisplayMode = mode;
            }
        }

        public void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItemCollection items = ddlDisplayMode.Items;
            int selectedIndex = items.IndexOf(items.FindByText(webPartManager.DisplayMode.Name));
            ddlDisplayMode.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved this code outside the postback section and it works fine now.

```
// move to container in masterpage
            Control control = (Control)Master.FindControl("divReturnBack");
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Visible = true;
                control.Controls.Add(DisplayModeMenul1);
            }
```